# Applying value (calculated with Firestore data) to label triggers "unwrapping an Optional value" crash

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uilabel

I have price list of ingredients, stored in Cloud Firestore. I want to calculate price for specific recepie, pass it to another VC and apply to label, so I wrote this code:

```
extension RecepiesViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    //Passing data to next VC
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
        destinationVC.result = totalPrice
    }
    //Recepie cell pressed
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        // Calculating price for recepie
        func recepieCalculation(_ completion: @escaping (Double) ->()) {     
            for ingridients in cakeRecepies![indexPath.item].ingridientList {
                db.collection("Okey")
                    .document(ingridients.name)
                    .getDocument() { (document, error) in
                        if let document = document, document.exists {
                            let data = document.data()
                            if let price = data!["price"] as? Double, let count = data!["count"] as? Int  {
                                let priceForOne = price / Double(count)
                                self.totalPrice = self.totalPrice + priceForOne * Double(ingridients.count)
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }
                        completion(self.totalPrice)
                }
            }
        }
        recepieCalculation {totalPrice in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Another VC code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    var result: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print(result)
            resultLabel.text = String(format: ".%f", result)
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var recepieImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

And at line `resultLabel.text = String(format: ".%f", result)` got error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly
>   unwrapping an Optional value

What could be wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: looks like your label outlet is not connected to storyboard.

Comment: 1. No, I don't have any force unwrappers "!" . 2. Label was connected, checked it twice

Comment: @MaxGavrilov, `1. No, I don't have any force unwrappers "!" .` — **false**: `@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!`

Comment: Also, before `viewDidLoad` is called **all** outlets are `nil`. So if `didSet` for `result` is called before `viewDidLoad`, then `resultLabel` is `nil`.

Comment: 'Also, before viewDidLoad is called all outlets are nil. So if didSet for result is called before viewDidLoad, then resultLabel is nil. 'Thanks, didn't  know about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

At the moment the destination controller of the segue is going to be presented the outlets are not connected yet, so assigning the value to the label in the `didSet` observer crashes.

Solution:

- Delete the observer

  ```
  var result = 0.0
  ```
- and assign the value in `viewDidLoad`

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      print(result)
      resultLabel.text = String(format: ".%f", result)
  }
  ```